# Aliasing or replacing external modules doesn't work

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

I have following rollup config:

```js
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import replacement from 'rollup-plugin-module-replacement';

/* ... */

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
        file: 'lib/index.js',
        format: 'amd',
        exports: 'named',
        intro: 'var global = window;',
        name: this.options.name,
    },
    external: ['axios'],
    plugins: [
        // both don't work as expected with external declared above
        alias({
            entries: [
                { find: 'axios', replacement: 'cdn/axios' },
            ],
        }),
        replacement({
            entries: [
                { find: 'axios', replacement: 'cdn/axios' },
            ],
        }),
        nodeResolve(/* ... */),
        commonjs(/* ... */),
        typescript(/* ... */),
    ],
};
```

This produces following code:

```js
define(['exports', 'axios'], function (exports, axios) { 'use strict'; // ...
```

But I'm expecting:

```js
define(['exports', 'cdn/axios'], function (exports, axios) { 'use strict'; // ...
```

Is there a way to rename those modules in upper scope define?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used output.paths property and it works as I needed.

Thanks [isidrok's answer about the issue on github](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/3814#issuecomment-706588315)